# How to increase the performance in Android Studio

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, memory

I was wondering how to increase the performance of Android Studio?

I have 16GB of RAM and I'm using SSD, but still, it's somewhat laggy.

Here's an example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3qSlMN5l40

Comment: You should upgrade CPU also. find 12 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably try to increase heap size.

1. Click File > Settings from the menu bar (or Android Studio > Preferences on macOS).
2. Click Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Memory Settings.
3. Adjust the heap sizes to match your desired amounts.
4. Click Apply.
5. Restart Android Studio so that settings could be applied.
6. For more details: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config

[image]